converting adcx adox operations on platforms that do not support them
trying to understand/do conversion of adcx adox assembly to instructions that do not support them
assembly code:
https://github.com/zkbitcoin/ffiasm/blob/master/benchmark/fr.asm
idea is to convert calls to adcx and adox (in examples below) to adc etc (on unsupported platforms)
adcx example:
; FirstLoop
    mov  rdx,[rsi + 0]
    mulx rax,r11,[rcx]
    mulx r8,r12,[rcx +8]
    adcx r12,rax
    mulx rax,r13,[rcx +16]
    adcx r13,r8
    mulx r8,r14,[rcx +24]
    adcx r14,rax
    mov  r15,r10
    adcx r15,r8


adcx and adox examples

; SecondLoop
    mov  rdx,r9
    mulx rax,rdx,r11
    mulx r8,rax,[q]
    adcx rax,r11
    mulx rax,r11,[q +8]
    adcx r11,r8
    adox r11,r12
    mulx r8,r12,[q +16]
    adcx r12,rax
    adox r12,r13
    mulx rax,r13,[q +24]
    adcx r13,r8
    adox r13,r14
    mov r14,r10
    adcx r14,rax
    adox r14,r15


reference
"New Instructions Supporting Large Integer Arithmetic on Intel® Architecture Processors"
https://caxapa.ru/thumbs/808576/ia-large-integer-arithmetic-paper.pdf

You will have more problems with the MULX than the ADCX. The latter can simply be replaced with plain ADC since you don't care about the other flags. It's not immediately obvious why the second block ends with the ADOX. Given that the rest of the instructions don't modify OF that will use the value set before the block (which is not shown). If that is intended, you can save that and emulate ADOX at the end. EDIT: yeah in your full github code the OF is used in another chain so you will need to emulate that.

thank you @Jester , if I understand correctly


cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep adx so adcx and adox is not available if run they created invalid ops (mulx however appears available)


adcx replaces adc


not clear here adox can be emulated but with which instruction


also chatgpt says about adox
adox r11,r12
ADD r11, r12  ; Add the values of r11 and r12
ADC r11, 0    ; Add the carry flag (which is effectively unchanged in this operation)
The ADD instruction adds the values of r11 and r12.
The ADC instruction then adds the carry flag (which is effectively the same as adding 0).

@Jester
"your full github code the OF is used in another chain" ? which asm line do you see that does that ?

I see you have found it :D

@Jester lol pretty funny , ok will give it a shot, bit of assembly know how never hurt anybody aka the foundations

Instead of emulating each ADOX one by one, you should probably separate the two chains. If you want any kind of performance that is.

In the first snippet you can simply use ADC since you don't care about the other flags. At least in the part of the code shown.
The second one is more complicated. Instead of emulating each ADOX one by one you should probably separate the two chains. But if you don't particularly care about speed just want something that works, you can allocate a variable in memory or a free register, say tempOF, and replace ADOX with:
rcr tempOF, 1  ; save CF and bring in old OF value
adc op2, op1   ; emulate ADOX with ADC
rcl tempOF, 1  ; update emulated OF and bring back saved CF

